# Are single and double quotes valid characters in postgres passwords?

Tags: postgresql

I am writing a bash script which has to deal with postgres passwords. Couldn't find any clear reference to know if single and double quotes are allowed in Postgres passwords. Need to know if that is a valid use case to begin with.

Please quote references for your answers.

Comment: yes, they are valid. ANY character is valid. but some are not reasonable to use. eg you can even use UTF passwords, but I would not use tab

Answer (score 3):

yes, they are valid. ANY character is valid. but some are not reasonable to use. eg you can even use UTF passwords, but I would not use tab, demo:

```
db=# do $$ begin execute format('create user s password %L ',concat(chr(10),chr(9),'a')); end;$$;
DO
```

demo of requiring the valid password:

```
db=#  select * from dblink('postgresql://s:badPass@1.1.1.1:5432/t','select now()') as t (t timestamptz);
ERROR:  could not establish connection
DETAIL:  FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "s"
```

demo of successfull login:

```
db=#  select * from dblink('postgresql://s:'||concat(chr(10),chr(9),'a')||'@1.1.1.1:5432/t','select now()') as t (t timestamptz);
               t
-------------------------------
 2018-01-08 13:20:45.149144+00
(1 row)
```

or:

```
[postgres@1 ~]$ export PGPASSWORD=$(echo -e "\n\ta")
[postgres@1 ~]$ psql -h 1.1.1.1 -p 5432 -U s
Timing is on.
psql (9.5.4)
Type "help" for help.
s=>
```

but now imagine you have to put password in terminal using a keyboard - how cosy you can use new line and tabulation, entering password?..

thus again - any char is allowed for password, but not all recommended

Answer (score 0):

if you do

```
create user s password 'my''Pass'
alter user s password 'my''Pass'
```

single quote characters must be escaped with another single quote